# Azure Service that can schedule my API calls in AKS

Tags: azure, function, azure-aks, job-scheduling

I have this .NET long running API process/function that usually runs 30 mins in one execution that is hosted in AKS. This API is usually executed from the users coming from the front end of the app.

Due to concurrent executions from users, this is causing exhaustion of the app so I'm planning to implement a some sort of a queueing mechanism with the help of a scheduler(s).

What possibly is applicable Azure service that can execute my API in AKS on a scheduled basis (let's say every minute) and possibly check the database for some flagging values.

I need a way to check the table for some flagging value if there a currently running process or its been completed so it can process the next one, otherwise ignore the call until current on is complete.

I was looking into Azure Web Apps, Web Jobs or Batch Jobs but kinda confused which is applicable with my case.

Please advise thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your API implemented in ASP.NET Core (or similar) and hosted in AKS?

Comment: just hosted in AKS. its just .NET framework 4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options here.

1. [Hangfire](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-queues.html)

Hangfire is an open-source library that can run background jobs in queues. In your case, you can enqueue each request from the client in a queue. Then Hangfire server will process them one by one (even with retry if the job fails). Hangfire supports SQL Server or Redis. You can query the storage to see the status of the queued jobs.

Hangfire can also run scheduled jobs, which will take care of that only one job run at a time.

2. Azure Service Bus

A more expensive option is to use Azure Service Bus for your queueing capability. For scheduled jobs, you can use [AKS CronJobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) but you will
implement the check yourself to see if there is a job already running.

Overall, I would recommend Hangfire, which can meet your requirements and is cheaper.

Comment: thank you for AKS Cron Job advise, this is very useful. my other question though; is cron job capable of running on multiple thread? Let's say for example I run the cron job every 5 minutes, but for some reason (due to long running tasks) the last or previous run is taking more than 5 minutes and still in progress, what will happen when the next run fires, will there be a new thread created capable of doing some business logic like checking for job in progress without disrupting the previous running job?